# sql next entered record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table "users" (simplified for the purposes of this question) with non-incremental ids (not my design but I have to live with it)

```
userUUID                                email
----------------------------------------------------
44384582-11B1-4BB4-A41A-004DFF1C2C3     dabac@sdfsd.com
3C0036C2-04D8-40EE-BBFE-00A9A50A9D81    sddf@dgfg.com
20EBFAFE-47C5-4BF5-8505-013DA80FC979    sdfsd@ssdfs.com
...
```

We are running a program that loops through the table and sends emails to registered users. Using a try/catch block, I am recording the UUID of a failed record in a text file. The program then ceases and would need restarting.

When the program is restarted, I don't want to resend emails to those that were successful, but begin at the failed record. I assume this means, I need to process records that were created AFTER the failed record.

How do I do this?

Comment: Can you post the structure of the table (i.e. post all columns)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. sort by a column (in this case I would recommend `userUUID`)
2. do a `where userUUID > 'your-last-uuid'`

Answer (score 6):

Why not keep track somewhere (e.g. another table, or even in a BIT column of the original table, called "WelcomeEmailSent" or something) which UUIDs have already been mailed? Then no matter where your program dies or what state it was in, it can start up again and always know where it left off.

Comment: Thanks, that's the way we originally had it, but now we are trying to keep as much as possible out of the database. For 80,000 records, the transaction log bulks after updating every flag column (though I suppose we could only update the flag of the failed column). Using this method, we simply record the ID of the failed record and nothing else.

Comment: @user460114 If you're going to keep it out of the database, and bypass transactional consistency, then why not store it in a table in another database, that is in simple recovery mode? You don't lose anything in terms of consistency, but the other database won't have heavy log impact.

Comment: The program does one read of the database to obtain the email addresses. After that, no further database transactions are necessary. As long as we sort the query by the UUID column, we shouldn't miss any records added belatedly.

Comment: So where does the program store 'your-last-uuid'? If it crashes in the middle of sending an e-mail, let's say, or someone trips on the power cord? When you start the program back up, if you haven't recorded anything to the database, how does the program know where it left off? Why are you using a database at all, why not just put your 80,000 rows in a flat file, now you don't have to worry about the database...

Comment: Since you think 80,000 rows is a lot and that updating a bit flag on those rows is going to be more expensive than sorting by a GUID... well, I'll just leave it at that. :-(

Comment: The UUID is stored in a text file. The program checks this file before running the query. The database is necessary for user registrations, which include the email address. It's not that 80K is necessarily a lot, but space on this particular database is already at a premium and this program has been pushing it to the limit. And the UUID is the primary key so it's automatically indexed and actually probably doesn't need a specific sort on it.

Comment: If space is at a premium, the first thing I would toss out are those GUIDs.

Comment: Sure, I would love to. But, as I said in the question, I have to live with the database and cannot change it. Changing that would affect processing for creating, updating and deleting records. More work, they don't want to pay.